# Not able to install facebook android sdk in xamarin android application

Tags: android, xamarin, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on xamarin android application.When I try to install facebook android sdk in my application it takes too much time and at last it stops with : some required packages are not referenced by the project.
And if I download facebook-android-sdk from facebook developer account then how to add it to my application ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding it through the NuGet package manager:

1. Right click the packages folder in your project
2. Select *Add Packages*
3. Type *Facebook SDK Xamarin Android* in the search box
4. Double-click the package

This should install the SDK and all its dependencies. All you need to do now is resolve it's namespaces and you should be good to go. You can check the *Package Console* pad for any errors.